# Flash: addEventListener not detecting Paste events in Input Text boxes

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, event-handling, copy-paste

I'm new to Flash, and I can't seem to do this simple action.

(I'm using ActionScript 3.0)

I created an input text box in my editor.  The instance name is "test".
In my Action editor I have this:

```
import flash.events.Event;
this.test.addEventListener(Event.PASTE, pasteHandler);

function pasteHandler(e:Event)
{
    trace("blaaaaaaaaaagh");
}
```

When I run it, it doesn't detect any of my paste events, whether I'm doing Ctrl+V or right-click+paste.  If I use another event, like MouseEvent.CLICK, it detects it fine.  In fact, I don't think any Event.XXX events (like COPY, INIT, etc.) are detected (at least from the ones I tried).  All of the MouseEvent and KeyboardEvent events seem to work fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dispatch Paste Event in AS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559409/dispatch-paste-event-in-as3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextField objects do not dispatch clear, copy, cut, paste, or selectAll events. Sorry for the bad news!

Tyler.

Comment: You could extend it and add that functionality your self (you would have to monitor which keys are pressed) but the suggestion below is good too.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is to listen for TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT and prevent the default behavior:

```
textField.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, onTextInput );

function onTextInput( e:TextEvent ) : void
{
    // this takes place of PASTE because Event.PASTE is not triggered on a textfield
    var t:TextField = TextField( e.currentTarget );
    t.replaceSelectedText( e.text );
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd listen for Event.CHANGE since pasting is going to change the field.

Comment: Event.CHANGE doesn't appear to fire when you set myField.text = "foo".  Is there some alternate way to add text to a field that provokes the CHANGE event?