# Dispatch Paste Event in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, paste

This is my AS3 code for a textbox with an instance name of `myTextBox` placed on stage -:

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

myTextBox.text = 'Hello India';
myTextBox.addEventListener(Event.PASTE, onPaste)

function onPaste(e:Event):void
{
    trace("lol");
}
```

But when i paste some text into the text box, nothing happens. Can't figure out the issue. Thanks for help...

Comment: may be _TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT_ will help you, because as mentioned Allan _TextField_ doesn't dispatch _Event.PASTE_ event.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#PASTE:

> Note: TextField objects do not dispatch clear, copy, cut, paste, or
>   selectAll events. TextField objects always include Cut, Copy, Paste,
>   Clear, and Select All commands in the context menu. You cannot remove
>   these commands from the context menu for TextField objects. For
>   TextField objects, selecting these commands (or their keyboard
>   equivalents) does not generate clear, copy, cut, paste, or selectAll
>   events. However, other classes that extend the InteractiveObject
>   class, including components built using the Flash Text Engine (FTE),
>   will dispatch these events in response to user actions such as
>   keyboard shortcuts and context menus.

So the easiest option is to use a TLF TextField. (Make sure to publish for Flash Player 10)

Comment: A TLF textfield is a feature rich text field. It was introduced with Flash Player 10. If you are creating the text field with the Flash IDE then on the properties panel of your textfield change it from Classic Text to TLF Text. Otherwise see this link for how to code it manually http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/text/TLFTextField.html